# ExtJS Tree panel binding

Tags: extjs

Iam design A ExtJS Combo with TreePanel

How to bind treePanel from Database(Please provide any sample code)
How to give url to treepanel and how to set as parent and child...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tree:

```
var tree= new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 300,
    useArrows: true,                    
    animate: true,
    border: false,
    root: {
        nodeType: 'async',
        text: 'Gallery',
        draggable: false, 
        id: '0'                       
    },
    loader: {
        url: '/Url to your server side for getting your tree data',
        requestMethod: 'GET'
    },
});
```

You need to code your server side to return your tree data as json. Here is an example:

```
[
  {id:'1',text:'First Data',leaf:true},
  {id:'2',text:'Second Data',leaf:true}
]
```

If you need to change or set the URL using APIs, you can do it like this:

```
treeObject.getLoader().url = "/Your new Url to server side";
```

Majority of the time we load new nodes through an URL. There is no specific APIs for creating a parent or child. Can you explain what you are trying to do?